# Why forEach return void?

Tags: javascript

I'm using Typescript for a Node application and I love to fully use the power of Javascript with all the good stuff of Typescript. Line after line I took up the habit to chain functions, to use arrow functions, to user carrying and partial functions and so on.

What I really cannot understand is why the `forEach` function return `void` instead of something useful I can use to perform a chainable, just one-line and elegant piece of code.

My question is about the **design considerations** behind this choice that at first glance seems to be just annoying and the implications a return value can cause.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.map` if you want to return for each item or `Array.prototype.reduce` for a single value.

Comment: "**design considerations**" are not primarily opinion-based. My questions is intended to be technical and I hope someone really expert in language design would answer to my question.

Answer (score 11):

Because that's what `forEach` does. It's like a `for` loop; it isn't meant to evaluate to anything useful. It's intended to be used to carry out side effects using a function. If you need it for anything other than that purpose, it's the wrong tool for the job.

If you want a looping function that evaluates to something, use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead. `map` will return a new list based on the old list, and `reduce` will return a reduced value from iterating over the list.

Comment: I won't mark your answer as correct since I've asked the **design consideration** behind the forEach func, instead of getting alternatives I already know. Thanks for your time btw